# Put RSA private key in iPhone keychain using SecItemAdd

Tags: ios, rsa, keychain, private-key, seckeyref

I generated a private PKCS#12 key and then put it in PEM format, and sent it over to the iPhone app. I want to save this private key in the iPhone Keychain.

First, I removed the headers like "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY". Then I converted the rest of it into `NSData`. Then, using code like this:

[CFDictionaryRef issues in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704394/cfdictionaryref-issues-in-swift)

I was able to get a `SecKeyRef` from this private key.

Now I want to know how I can insert this `SecKeyRef` into the keychain using `SecItemAdd`?

Comment: have u tried to use any library ?

Comment: No, what library would you suggest?

Comment: like - https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess or https://github.com/soffes/SSKeychain

Comment: These libraries aren't that helpful, since I am trying to put a private Key, which is a PKCS12 converted NSData. I already converted it to SecKeyRef, just haven't figured out how to add a SecKeyRef, thats it.

Comment: try to convert SecKeyRef to nsdata again and store in keychain

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method to convert `SecKeyRef` to `NSData`

```
- (NSData *)getPublicKeyBitsFromKey:(SecKeyRef)givenKey {

    static const uint8_t publicKeyIdentifier[] = "com.your.company.publickey";
    NSData *publicTag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier length:sizeof(publicKeyIdentifier)];

    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData * publicKeyBits = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];

    // Temporarily add key to the Keychain, return as data:
    NSMutableDictionary * attributes = [queryPublicKey mutableCopy];
    [attributes setObject:(__bridge id)givenKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueRef];
    [attributes setObject:@YES forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
    CFTypeRef result;
    sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributes, &result);
    if (sanityCheck == errSecSuccess) {
        publicKeyBits = CFBridgingRelease(result);

        // Remove from Keychain again:
        (void)SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) queryPublicKey);
    }

    return publicKeyBits;
}
```

And then add it to keychain.
I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. Convert the private key to PKCS#8 format.
2. Strip header
3. Add to keychain

These two libs could help:
Swift: https://github.com/btnguyen2k/swift-rsautils
Obj-C: https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA

Comment: How do you convert the private key to PKCS#8?